# Source of electromagnetic signal in kHz regime

Tags: noise, antenna, rf

I was wondering what emits electromagnetic signals in the kHz regime? When I touch the inner pin of an BNC cable connected to an oscilloscope, I see a large sinusoidal signal with ca 40 kHz.

Comment: Are you definitely sure it isn't AC from power cables i.e. 50 or 60Hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cold Cathode Fluorescent Lamp [(CCFL) inverters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCFL_inverter) are sometimes designed for the 20 to 60 KHz frequency range. The CCFL desk magnifier lamp at my workbench emits EMI at 32 KHz, and shows the same effect on my oscilloscope as described in the question.

Also, [high frequency electronic ballast](http://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/NLPIP/pdf/VIEW/Guide2.pdf) circuits for domestic fluorescent tubes work in the same frequency range of 20 KHz to 60 KHz.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any wall wart or other SMPS nowadays could be a possible culprit as well as the CCFL lights Anindo mentions. Cheapness (poor EMC suppression) and proximity are the most likely causal factors. Move your other hand round, close to possible culprits or their power cables, observing changes in the waveform. Switch lights off, then other equipment, one by one until you find it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to take a look at this video: [EEVblog #441 – How To Track Down Common Mode Noise](http://www.eevblog.com/2013/03/22/eevblog-441-how-to-track-down-common-mode-noise/)